# Django comment form

Tags: python, html, django

I am following the guide to create comment given by Django central, https://djangocentral.com/creating-comments-system-with-django/ and it is working. However I am using the `{{ form.as_p }}` Which will give 3 fields, as the form say, with name, email and the body. But i wanted to have predefined name, which would be your username you are logged inn with and the email attached to that account. How would i go ahead to create that?

forms.py

```
class CommentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Comment
        fields = ['name', 'email', 'body']
```

models.py

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, related_name='comments', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    email = models.EmailField()
    body = models.TextField()

    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-date_added']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

views.py

```
def post_detail(request, category_slug, slug, status=Post.ACTIVE):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, slug=slug)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CommentForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
           comment = form.save(commit=False)
           comment.post = post
           comment.save()

           return redirect('post_detail',  category_slug=category_slug, slug=slug)
    else:
        form = CommentForm()

    return render(request, 'blog/post_detail.html', {'post': post, 'form': form})
```

in the html template

```
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
    <h2 class="subtitle is-4">Comments</h2>
<form method="post" class="mb-6">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <div class="field">
        <div class="control">
            <button class="button is-success">Submit comment</button>
         </div>
    </div>
</form>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Did your user is authenticated while he is posting comment ?

Comment: The user.is_auth is so only authenticated users can see the form, then it should not be necessary to need to write a name and email, when user is authenticated already have a name and email to his/her account

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to pre-set the username and email fields, you can use the `initial` form parameters like this:

## views.py

```
def post_detail(request, category_slug, slug, status=Post.ACTIVE):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, slug=slug)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CommentForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
           comment = form.save(commit=False)
           comment.post = post
           comment.save()

           return redirect('post_detail',  category_slug=category_slug, slug=slug)
    else:
        user = request.user
        form = CommentForm(initial={"name": user.username, "email": user.email})

        return render(request, 'blog/post_detail.html', {'post': post, 'form': form})
```

## forms.py

```
class CommentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['name'].disabled = True
        self.fields['email'].disabled = True 
        
       # OR set readonly widget attribute.
       # self.fields['name'].widget.attrs['readonly'] = True
       # self.fields['email'].widget.attrs['readonly'] = True

    class Meta:
        model = Comment
        fields = ['name', 'email', 'body']
```

Comment: Ok, that works, but still the name and email fields can be changed. How do I deal with that so that there is no option to change the name and email?

Comment: You can use the disabled argument or readonly attribute when creating a field, but you are now using the meta class.
To do this you can override the `__init__` method(I updated the answer, you can see how to do it there).

Comment: Just one last question, lets say someone without username want to access the site, they cannot write comments, but now because of the change in forms, i get error no email in object when trying to access the detail post page. Due to email being read only.

Comment: You can add the some condition like `if user.username:` then add `initial` parameter otherwise use `form=CommentForm()`